# How to disable this behaviour on a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application with a ListView.

I want to disable this:

I have a ListView with three list items. When I press over the first list and, without releasing, I move down through second item and third item. Then, when my finger is over the third item I release it. After that I see that all of them has a black background.

How can I disable this effect?

If you need more details, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your ListView element inside your XML file:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

**However**, if your app has a background that is a solid color, then set the cacheColorHint to that color, as having it set to transparent can lead to slow scrolling. For example, if I had a green background:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#0F0"
```

Comment: No, it has an image as background: `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_gates_bkg" >`.

Comment: Just use a transparent color then, if it's too slow, then don't use a image as a background, and use a solid color. If you have a optimised list adapter and are on a half decent phone, then smoothness shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I have a XML used as ListActivity layout and a XML to ListView item. Where I have to add `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"`?

Comment: Put the `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` in the ListView inside the activity's XML file, not the list row's XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

as one of the ListView attributes. This will disable the color caching, which will stop doing this black thing.